# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Lesson 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Update Saturday April 23, 2011

Lesson is green after implementing the following in user.rb

```
def authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
  user = find_by_id(id)
  (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil 
end
```

I get:

```
Failures:

  1) SessionsController POST 'create' success should sign the user in
     Failure/Error: controller.current_user.should == @user
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
     # ./app/models/user.rb:45:in `authenticate_with_salt'
     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:36:in `user_from_remember_token'
     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `current_user'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:58:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.54296 seconds
7 examples, 1 failure
```

I am continuing to investigate... oh the joy! :D

EDIT: Working on finishing lesson 9 then will post back here -- seems that im back onto the path finding the problem myself again thanks to GrahamJRoy!

Update Friday April 22, 2011 :

I've spent the last day trying to find the similar problem but have been sorely unsuccessful, if you need any more information please let me know, both failures are highly likely related to each other so if i fix one i think it will fix the other

```
Failures:

  1) SessionsController POST 'create' success should sign the user in
     Failure/Error: post :create, :session => @attr
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `clear_return_to' for #<SessionsController:0x00000101648ac8>
     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:28:in `redirect_back_or'
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:51:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) SessionsController POST 'create' success should redirect to the user show page
     Failure/Error: post :create, :session => @attr
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `clear_return_to' for #<SessionsController:0x00000100ea0690>
     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:28:in `redirect_back_or'
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:57:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.42858 seconds
7 examples, 2 failures
```

In sessions helper.rb file:

```
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    clear_return_to
  end
```

In sessions_controller_spec.rb file:

```
  it "should sign the user in" do
     post :create, :session => @attr
     controller.current_user.should == @user
     controller.should be_signed_in
   end

  it "should redirect to the user show page" do
     post :create, :session => @attr
     response.should redirect_to(user_path(@user))
   end


In sessions_controller.rb file:

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                             params[:session][:password])
    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
      @title = "Sign in"
      render 'new'
    else
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    end
  end
```

Original Problem below:

---

I'm currently working in Lesson 9 on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and am getting the following error when running autotest:

Failures:

```
  1) SessionsController POST 'create' success should sign the user in
     Failure/Error: post :create, :session => @attr
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sign_in' for #<SessionsController:0x000001017082d8>
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:15:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:51:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) SessionsController POST 'create' success should redirect to the user show page
     Failure/Error: post :create, :session => @attr
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sign_in' for #<SessionsController:0x00000100ecbca0>
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:15:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:57:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

sessions_controller_spec.rb:

```
  it "should sign the user in" do
    post :create, :session => @attr
    controller.current_user.should == @user
    controller.should be_signed_in
  end

  it "should redirect to the user show page" do
    post :create, :session => @attr
    response.should redirect_to(user_path(@user))
  end
```

IF i comment out the above sessions_controller_spec.rb I will be GREEN! Possibly that will help someone guide me in the right direction as I am clueless!

sessions_controller.rb:

```
def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                             params[:session][:password])
    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
      @title = "Sign in"
      render 'new'
    else
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    end
  end
```

sessions_helper.rb:

```
def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
  self.current_user = user
end
```

ADDED per GrahamJRoy 'include SessionsHelper' in application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

2 new errors that I think are leading to my problem:

Failures:

```
  1) SessionsController POST 'create' success should sign the user in
     Failure/Error: post :create, :session => @attr
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `redirect_back_or' for #<SessionsController:0x0000010405adc0>
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:51:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) SessionsController POST 'create' success should redirect to the user show page
     Failure/Error: post :create, :session => @attr
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `redirect_back_or' for #<SessionsController:0x000001030a3c60>
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:57:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 5):

Per the documentation, have you referenced the SessionsHelper in the ApplicationController?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

Comment: hmm nope I tried adding that to the application_controller.rb file and it killed autotest: "SAMPLE_APP: COULD NOT RUN TESTS"

Comment: should be include SessionsHelper  (with s)  -- now 2 different errors

Comment: sorry for the typo. It now sounds like you're missing the following method in your sessions_helper: def redirect_back_or(default) see listing 10.17

Answer (score 0):

So I basically backtracked and started the lesson over again and carefully commented out the code on each page that shouldnt be there.

My Saturday update above made me start inspecting what the failure was showing, so I went to each line it mentioned and checked RailsTutorial git repo to see any obvious differences.

This led to the * next to the remember_token

```
User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
```

When adding that * the error changed from

```
Failures:

  1) SessionsController POST 'create' success should sign the user in
     Failure/Error: controller.current_user.should == @user
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
     # ./app/models/user.rb:45:in `authenticate_with_salt'
     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:36:in `user_from_remember_token'
     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `current_user'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:58:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.54296 seconds
7 examples, 1 failure
```

to:

```
Failures:

  1) SessionsController POST 'create' success should sign the user in
     Failure/Error: controller.should be_signed_in
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `signed_in?' for #<SessionsController:0x00000104086088>
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:59:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.73 seconds
63 examples, 1 failure
```

At which point i checked my code:

```
  def signed_in
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

to the git repoos:

```
  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

And conveniently saw a '?' missing which I figured I would add and see what happens..

And apparently I'm green now... lets finish this lesson now!

Many thanks to GrahamJRoy for your input!